# Oracle json_object with large content resulting in ORA-40459

Tags: json, oracle

I'm trying to build JSON with Oracle functions like json_object out of large tables. There are multiple nesting levels, e.g. I'm using `json_arrayagg` inside a json_object. So I'm reaching the limit of the return datatype very fast. The default datatype is `varchar2(4000)`. Of course I can extend this up to `varchar2(32767)` or even clob by specifying RETURNING-keyword. But clob is only supported by `json_objectagg` and json_arrayagg and even extending to 32767 doesn't seem to work in every case. I'm still getting `ORA-40459` despite the fact that i specified `varchar2(32767)`.

Is there a way to extend this limitation? These functions don't seem to be very useful with limitations like this!

Or are there other ways to perform this task? The problem in my case is the huge amount of data I have to export. Therefore it isn't possible to perform this task in the client. Maybe it is possible to do this in PL/SQL, but I'm not sure about the performance. And i would have to use a 3rd party library like pljson, which needs to be installed.

Comment: This probably will not help but worth reading.
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9536628700346446955
Maybe using pl/sql with many variables to split the return datatype into many variables then concatenate them later...

Comment: I considered using PL/SQL, doing work in some subroutines and replace placeholders afterwards. But this seems to be very complicated in cases where you use *agg-functions, because there might be [n] placeholders to replace.

Comment: So the only way left is to build my JSON with string concatenation?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a little too late. I had the same problem and I solved it by adding

**JSON_OBJECT(**...

*RETURN VARCHAR2(5000)* **)** As JSON_STRING

at the end of the json object statement before the closing paranthesis.

You can also add a RETURNING CLOB just to make sure